# Pro-rata costs for subscription update using recurly.js

Tags: recurly

We are looking to update our recurly subscription management page so that customers can select add-ons to their existing subscription.  However it doesn't look like you can get the pro-rata price of the update for the current month.

I've been looking through the code at: https://github.com/recurly/recurly-js

and don't see a way to attach the pricing object to a customers account.  So I suspect it's not possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recurly.js is really just designed for initial transactions when you're collecting the customer's billing information.

For everything else, you can use the regular API. The preview subscription call is what you're looking for: https://dev.recurly.com/docs/preview-subscription

Comment: That was what I thought, just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing anything